# Launching Android Weather App Via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to launch the stock weather app from my android app via an 
intent, but I keep getting a force close runtime error, and LogCat 
gives me nothing.  The code I am trying to use to achieve this is:

```
public void startWeatherActivity() { 
   Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
   intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("org.anddev.android.weatherforecast/
        org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.WeatherForecast")); 
   intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"); 
   startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get your intent from getLaunchIntentFromPackage:
[android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29)

just as a comment, you should use Intent.ACTION_MAIN instead of the explicit string constant.

Comment: OK, the problem was from using the wrong package for the app. But, using getLaunchIntentFromPackage was very helpful.