# Launch default weather application

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm looking for a way to launch the default weather application via an Intent. I tried to use the package name for Android's default weather app like indicated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748195/launching-android-weather-app-via-intent).

Other than that I looked on Android developer website for some clues but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should first get the `package` of that `android` `app` which you can find it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file then write this code where you want to launch that `weather application`

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String packageName = "com.your.packagename";
Intent launchIntent =  pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

And make sure the application is installed

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do it in an Android Wear app, and I managed to do it using this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511404/7006743

Here is my code to launch the default Android Wear weather app :

```java
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.google.android.wearable.app", "com.google.android.clockwork.home.search.apps.weather.WeatherActivity");
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

To find the component name, just start the desired app and check what happens in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

After june 2022 :

```
    localIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox", "com.google.android.apps.search.weather.WeatherExportedActivity");
                    startActivity(localIntent);
```